# How can I switch off the Cyrillic alphabet in google docs?

Tags: google-docs

I hit some key combination and suddenly I am typing Cyrillic letters. How can I undo this and go back to typing with standard Latin letters?

Comment: Sorry, why doesn't this post meet SO guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

It was [surprisingly hard to find](https://thenextweb.com/news/google-launches-new-text-input-tool-let-type-russian-chinese-hindi-within-google-docs) but the keyboard shortcut ist Cmd + Shift + K on a Mac or Ctrl + Shift + K on a PC.